# How to display the output of the View as json in the list of articles which use paragraphs?

Tags: views, paragraphs

I have a content type **Article** which has a ***field_paragraph*** field.

Also I created a Paragraph type: View Paragraph which has a **View reference** field

When I create an article, in the ***field_paragraph*** field I added a reference to a view in order to get the list of titles from another content type: **Basic Page**.

I'm using JSON API module in order to get the list of articles in json format for a front-end application.

The problem is that Views reference field is displaying the structure of the view and not the output of the view in JSON format. For another types of paragraphs (paragraphs with a Long Text field or an image field) is not a problem to get the results in json.